# Cannot construct instance of `org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile` error in spring boot

Tags: java, ajax, spring, spring-boot

I am trying to upload photo in my local disk.So,I am using spring boot.And I have used `MultipartFile` to upload the file.So,I have a basic form and when I click the submit button then the POST method of AJAX is called.

I have used  `<input type="file" name="files" />` to upload the file.

```
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="fileUploadForm">

    <div class="col-md-6">
        <input type="file" name="files" />
        <br/>
        <br/>

    </div>

    <label>iNumber</label>
    <input name="iNumber" name="iNumber" id="iNumber" type="text" class="form-control" required="required" />

    <label>Full Name:</label>
    <input name="fullName" name="fullName" id="fullName" type="text" class="form-control" required="required" />

    <label>Joined Date</label>
    <input name="joinedDate" id="joinedDate" type="text" class="form-control" required="required" />

    <label>Position</label>
    <input name="position" id="position" type="text" class="form-control" required="required" />

    <label>Reports To</label>
    <input name="reportsTo" id="reportsTo" type="text" class="form-control" required="required" />

    <label>Cubicle No</label>
    <input name="cubicleNo" id="cubicleNo" type="text" class="form-control" required="required" />

    <label>Job type</label>
    <input name="jobType" id="jobType" type="text" class="form-control" required="required" />

    <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="btnSubmit" />

</form>
```

And here comes my javascript part which is handling the form data as:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

        $('#btnSubmit').on('click',function() {

        //stop submit the form, we will post it manually.
        event.preventDefault();
         console.log("hitted");
        fire_ajax_submit();

    });

});

function fire_ajax_submit() {

var form = $('#fileUploadForm')[0];
console.log(form);
  var data = new FormData(form);
console.log(data);
 data.append("CustomField", "This is some extra data, testing");
 console.log(data);
var employee={
      "iNumber":$("#iNumber").val(),
       "fullName":$("#fullName").val(),
       "joinedDate":$("#joinedDate").val(),
         "position":$("#position").val(),
       "reportsTo":$("#reportsTo").val(),
        "cubicleNo":$("#cubicleNo").val(),
      "jobType":$("#jobType").val(),
      "files":data
};

    console.log(employee);

  $.ajax({
                    url: A_PAGE_CONTEXT_PATH + "/insert-emp",
                    method: "post",
                    contentType: "application/json",
                    dataType: "json",
                    data: JSON.stringify(employee),
                      success: function(response) {
                         console.log(response);
                         alert("Successfully Saved!");
                         window.location.reload(true);
                            }, error: function(response){
                        switch(response.status){
                            case 409:
                            alert("error");
                        }
                    }
                });

}
```

The JSON data I am sending looks like:

[image]

The Rest Api is :

```
@RestController
public class EmployeeController {

    @Autowired
    private EmployeeService empService;


    //Save the uploaded file to this folder
    private static String UPLOADED_FOLDER = "F://temp//";

    @PostMapping("/insert-emp")
    @ResponseBody
    public ResponseEntity<?> createEmployee(@Valid @RequestBody Employee employee) {
        MultipartFile uploadfile=employee.getFiles();
        System.out.println("entered here");
        if (uploadfile.isEmpty()) {
            return new ResponseEntity("please select a file!", HttpStatus.OK);
        }

        try {

            saveUploadedFiles(Arrays.asList(uploadfile));

        } catch (IOException e) {
            return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
        }
        return new ResponseEntity("Successfully uploaded - " +
                uploadfile.getOriginalFilename(), new HttpHeaders(), HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    //save file
    private void saveUploadedFiles(List<MultipartFile> files) throws IOException {

        for (MultipartFile file : files) {

            if (file.isEmpty()) {
                continue; //next pls
            }

            byte[] bytes = file.getBytes();
            Path path = Paths.get(UPLOADED_FOLDER + file.getOriginalFilename());
            Files.write(path, bytes);

        }

    }
}
```

My model class Employee.java is:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "employee")
public class Employee {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;

    @NotBlank
    private String iNumber;

    @NotBlank
    private String fullName;

//    @NotBlank
    private String joinedDate;

    @NotBlank
    private String position;

    @NotBlank
    private String reportsTo;

    @NotBlank
    private String cubicleNo;

    @NotBlank
    private String jobType;

    @Transient
    private MultipartFile files;

    public Employee() {
    }
//all getters and setters
}
```

I am getting error when I am submitting:

**com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: Cannot construct instance of `org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile` (no Creators, like default construct, exist): abstract types either need to be mapped to concrete types, have custom deserializer, or contain additional type information
 at [Source: (PushbackInputStream); line: 1, column: 141] (through reference chain: com.ashwin.vemployee.model.Employee["files"])**

Comment: This answer should help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25183266/45112

Comment: @Random guy, did you get solution for this...? I am also facing the same issue.